# How to write shader node's data to file use python API?

Tags: python, texturing, materials, shader-nodes

I'm a beginner and studying the procedural texture generation of Blender, each node we can think of it as a function y=f(x), I want to send some `x` data from extern files and get the node output `y` by python API.

For example, the Musgrave texture node receives `Vector` and outputs `Fac`, I want to give it lots of `Vector` values and record the corresponding `Fac`.

I found that the `Texture Node Editor` has API `bpy.data.textures["xxx"].evaluate()`, but it seems that `Texture Node Editor` is the older version, and the `Shader Node Editor`, `bpy.data.materials["xxx"]` doesn't have `.evaluate()` method. How do I work on materials?

Comment: Unless you have an input texture and want to bake the results to an output texture, I'm afraid you can't do that. This is mostly streamlined to the GPU and the evaluated data is not available to the API (AFAIK). You can however look into the source code for the implementation of the nodes if you know your way around C and use it in your own scripts.

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you! I baked the texture successfully! I think maybe if I want to query the specific `x`, a choice is to arrange all query coordinates to RGB color, form an image, then set it as the image texture, and link it to the procedural node, finally bake it. Can it work?

Comment: I think so, yes. Make sure you use raw color space when saving the image file though, or else you will have shifted values

Comment: @Gorgious Okay, thanks so much!